# Ubuntu 16.04 running on Acer Aspire ES1 571

Tags: 16.04, acer

I am trying to purchase a mid-range laptop which will be used with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Not an easy task in my country (Hungary) since it is practically impossible to get Ubuntu-preinstalled laptops here.

Does anybody have experience with the Acer Aspire ES1 571 series on Ubuntu 16.04?

- installation tricks necessary (if the Ubuntu installer fails on it by default)
- which hw components don't work at all after a default install
- which hw components work after a default install but only badly (e.g. low wifi performance because there are no proper drivers for Ubuntu but works normally under Windows)

Many thanks

---

Especially see comments in Answer 1.

Comment: All Acer have an unique requirement of setting a supervisory password in UEFI and enabling "trust" on the grub/ubuntu .efi files in the ESP - efi system partition. Should be very similar to: Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot & Acer Trust Settings - details, some now report that then secure boot has to be on to set trust:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358003 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2291335&p=13341757#post13341757

Comment: What’s your question? What you would you like to know *specifically*? Asking for open-ended opinions and personal experiences is off topic on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @David I have added clarifications to the question. I am specifically intersted in the state of hw support

Comment: @oldfred Thanks for the tip about the EFI dual boot

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However, you question is still too broad. Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: @David I think the question is fairly definite. Anyone can answer it properly who has already tried to install Ubuntu 16.04 on a unit of this line and nobody else can.  If nobody has tried it, then the question will not be answered at all (which I think is fine). When I buy the machine and try 16.04 on it, I will post an answer. Since Ubuntu has no up-to-date hw compatibility database (that I could find), AskUbuntu seems to be a good place for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu should be able to run on any laptop.

The [installation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation) points to the [hardware support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport) you should read if you have any doubts.

However, there's nothing in this laptop letting me think it could not run Ubuntu fluently. It's a typical configuration with typical components.

Comment: Thanks, I have checked the hw support pages but no info about this particular model (or any similar).

Comment: Your right in that it seems a fairly standard Intel hw set so probably not a big deal to run Ubuntu properly on it.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant indeed :)

Comment: Hw support seems near perfect after installation. 
The Ubuntu 16.04.2 (Unity) installer has failed ~ when starting copying files.  The Mint 18.2 Cinnamon variant did install but install progress was very slow and "No bootable device" error after restart, at boot. 

In BIOS config, the ubuntu.efi file had to be manually added to the allowed efi file list in Secure Boot config params, and allowing Secure Boot in general.

Comment: I personally like to deactivate both secure and fast boot for dual boot setup and linux installation in general.